# Drupal Crumbs can't get first "level" to show breadcrumb?

Tags: 7, breadcrumbs

I seem to be having a problem with Crumbs and I can't seem to figure it out. I have it setup to show

```
crumbs.home_title
path
menu.hierarchy.main-menu
*
```

But it doesn't seem to show anything for the very first level, anything under that shows fine. I can't seem to figure out what is going on. At least it should show the Home title?

Comment: What do you have for "Shortest visible breadcrumb" under /admin/structure/crumbs/display?

Comment: +_+ derp... that was it. It was set to only show if there was 3 levels.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As Clive said, this ended up being a configuration issue on my part.

Shortest visible breadcrumb under /admin/structure/crumbs/display was set to 3 levels.